# Reading parquet file by spark using wildcard

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have many parquet files in S3 directory. The directory structure may vary based on vid. something like this:

```
bucketname/vid=123/year=2020/month=9/date=12/hf1hfw2he.parquet
bucketname/vid=456/year=2020/month=8/date=13/34jbj.parquet
bucketname/vid=876/year=2020/month=9/date=15/ghg76.parquet
```

I have a list which contains all the vid something like this

```
vid_list = ['123','456','876']
```

How can I read all the files at once for month=9 with out effective performance issue?

```
current_month=9
temp_df = sqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema", "false").parquet('s3a://bucketname' + 'vid={}/year=2020/month={}/*/*.parquet'.format(*vid_list,current_month))
```

This is giving me error `Path does not exist: file:/Users/home/desktop/test1/vid=123/year=2020/month=456/*/*.parquet;`. Is there any way to achieve this in efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
vid_list = '(' + '|'.join(['123','456','876']) + ')'
current_month=9
temp_df = sqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema", "false").parquet('s3://bucketname/' + 'vid={}/year=2020/month={}/*/*.parquet'.format(vid_list,current_month))
// URL should look like: s3://bucketname/vid=(123|456|876)/year=2020/month=9/*/*.parquet
```

> Error in your code: Month value is **456**, it should be **9**

```
file:/Users/home/desktop/test1/vid=123/year=2020/month=456/*/*.parquet;
```

Comment: It's giving me error with path doesn't exists. `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/Users/home/desktop/test1/vid=(1asdf|ACNAUTOTSTPGACN03)/year=2020/month=6/*/*.parquet;`. the output string of my url is `'/Users/home/desktop/test1/vid=(1asdf|ACNAUTOTSTPGACN03)/year=2020/month=6/*/*.parquet'`

Comment: @PPARI1: Why is it going to machine file path instead of S3 Location? also values of vid is incorrect: `(1asdf|ACNAUTOTSTPGACN03)`. u need to check the arguments u r passing.

Comment: I am using different vid, that should be fine and testing locally that's why giving local path but it's failing..